# Redux: How to unit test an async action that dispatches another async action

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, action, redux

I'm having a hard time trying to test an async function that that dispatches another async function:

```
export function validateVerifyCode(payload, pin) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requesting());
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/register`).then(resp => {
        return resp.json()
      })
      .then(json => {
        dispatch(hasSubscriptionCheck(json));
        }
      })
      .catch(error => dispatch(hasError(error)))
  }
}

function hasSubscriptionCheck(payload) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requesting());
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/subscriptions`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(json => {
        if (json.length == 0) {
          dispatch(handleStripeSubmit(payload));
        }
      })
      .catch(error => dispatch(hasError(error)));
  }
}
```

The problem is in my unit test it doesn't actually call hasSubscriptionCheck:

```
  it('validates the verify code', (done) => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(Stripe.card, 'createToken');
    stub.onCall(0).returns(new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve({});
    }));


    nock(BASE_URL)
      .defaultReplyHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authentication': token
      })
      .post('/register')
      .reply(200, {id: 'userid1234'})
      .get('/^subscriptions')
      .reply(200, []);


    const store = mockStore({});

    const payload = {
...
    };

    store.dispatch(actions.validateVerifyCode(payload, '123456'))
      .then(() => {
        console.log(store.getActions());
      })
      .then(done)
      .catch(done);
  })
```

What's weird though is that when i console.log store.getActions(), I see 2 actions:

```
[ { type: 'REQUESTING' }, { type: 'REQUESTING' } ]
```

How I tell the test framework to invoke the second fetch?

Comment: It’s not obvious what `mockStore` is, would you please clarify which package you are using?

Comment: @DanAbramov the mockStore is from https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store. The original example I took from http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html, under async action creators